# add data to element so jquery's .data("key") works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see that jquery has a function `.data("key")` which returns the value for that key in the element it's called off of. I would like to use that method, but to do so I need to set the data using html. (I need to set it in my handlebars template helper before the element exists.)

For example, say I have the following html text:

```
'<button id=\"my-button\">button</button>');
```

And I want:

```
$('#my-button').data('datakey');
```

to return `42`, how would I do that in the html?

Alternately, if that is impractical to do, what way should I do it?

Comment: `<button id=\"my-button\" data-datakey="42">button</button>`?

Comment: ["HTML 5 `data-` attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object."](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

Comment: After 10 +1s I noticed that it would probably throw an exception, I forgot the backslashes lol

Comment: I wonder why this gets so many down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `data`, you need to have a `data-` style attribute: `<button id="my-button" data-key="42">button</button>`

OR set the value using the data function: `$('#my-button').data('key', 42);`

Then you can retrieve the value with `$('#my-button').data('key'); //returns 42`

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Huh, I didn't see the data-attribute html5 info when I was looking through the docs. Thanks for pointing out the link.

Answer (score 1):

To use `data()` generate html like this:

```
<button id="my-button" data-key="42">button</button>
```

Then:

```
// exactly without 'data' prefix 
$('#my-button').data('key');
// will return 42.
```

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, `$('#my-button').data('key')` will do the job if you have a `data-key` attribute, but this is true for jQuery >= 1.4.3.

Also, note that jQuery will do its best to convert the attribute value string into a JavaScript value (integer, array, object, etc.). So if you have

```
<button id="my-button" data-key='{"hello": "you", "lol": 42}'>button</button>
```

then `$('#my-button').data('key')` will return the object

```
{
    hello: 'you',
    lol: 42
}
```

and not the string `{"hello": "you", "lol": 42}`.

I tend to prefer `attr` instead of `data` for this. Even older browsers that do not support `data-` attributes will still keep this attribute into the element's DOM node, so with `attr`, you're always sure to get the **string value** of the attribute:

```
value = $('#my-button').attr('data-key');
```

Of course you have to provide the complete attribute name here, which is `data-key`. See the difference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cYWYR/) (look at your console).